# Is there a way to check if a rect intersects another on a specific side?

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering if there is a way to check if some rect x intersects with another rect y, but from a specific side. For eg: rect x is going upwards, and intersects with rect y. Since it was moving upwards, the function for checking if the intersection exists will return True (yes they did intersect) and "top" (top side of rect x has intersected with rect y). If there are multiple "sides" of rect x that are colliding with rect y, such as when they aren't perfectly lined up on one axis, then return the side whose length in the rect y is the longest. I will try and provide gifs to explain better.
So far I've tried:

- Checking every frame for intersections (`pygame.Rect.colliderect()`) and the velocities of the rects
- Using `pygame.Rect.collidepoint()` on multiple points on some side

Has anyone got any ideas? Thanks.
[image: aligned on axis]
[image: not aligned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare the x and y values of the rects and process the x and y axis individually.

```
rect_y = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 20, 20)
rect_x = pygame.Rect(10, 40, 20, 20)

def move_rect(rect, other_rect, velocity):
    rect.x += velocity[0]
    collision = ""
    if rect.colliderect(other_rect):
        if velocity[0] > 0:
            collision = "right"
        else:
            collision = "left"

    rect.y += velocity[1]
    collision = ""
    if rect.colliderect(other_rect):
        if velocity[1] > 0:
            collision = "bottom"
        else:
            collision = "top"
    return collision

# move rect_y up by 10 pixels
move_rect(rect_y, rect_x, (0, -10))
```